# "list indices must be integers" - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I have input as below:

```
"custom_fields": "[{"id":360027795053,"value":"XXXX"}, 
                   {"id":360030272393,"value":"XXX"}, 
                   {"id":360027795613,"value":XXX}, 
                   {"id":360027795393,"value":"XXX"}, 
                   {"id":360027795413,"value":"XXX"}, 
                   {"id":360030272233,"value":"XXX"},
                   {"id":360027795453,"value":["XXX"]}]"
```

I access the above as follows:

```
dict_conversion=json.loads(custom_fields)

properties['field_1']=dict_conversion['360027795053']['value']
```

The above gives the following error:

> list indices must be integers

Looks like i am trying the call the elements by their name, but its not allowing to call. I can only call by the index number as follows:

```
 properties['field_1']=dict_conversion[1]['value']
```

But I prefer to call by key-name.

Any help- appreciated.

Comment: As well as your actual error `360027795053` and `'360027795053'` are different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first converting to a dict with the id being the key and the value being it's value

```
custom_fields = [{"id":360027795053,"value":"XXXX"},
                   {"id":360030272393,"value":"XXX"},
                   {"id":360027795613,"value":"XXX"},
                   {"id":360027795393,"value":"XXX"},
                   {"id":360027795413,"value":"XXX"},
                   {"id":360030272233,"value":"XXX"},
                   {"id":360027795453,"value":"XXX"}]
id_dict = {i['id']: i['value'] for i in custom_fields}
print(id_dict)
>>> {360027795053: 'XXXX', 360030272393: 'XXX', 360027795613: 'XXX', 360027795393: 'XXX', 360027795413: 'XXX', 360030272233: 'XXX', 360027795453: 'XXX'}
```

Now if you want to get the value for a given id, you can call it using:

```
print(id_dict[360027795053])
>>> XXXX
```

If you don't want to do this, you can also loop over your list, something like this:

```
search_id = 360027795053
for i in custom_fields:
    if i['id'] == search_id:
        print(i['value'])
        break
```